# Search and exclude rows in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

I have a HTML table with over a thousand rows and it's only getting bigger.
I use this function to search the data in the table.

```
function mySFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("mySInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and an input box of

```
<input type="text" id="mySInput" onkeyup="mySFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
```

This works fine, I can find whatever I type in the box.
But I need another input box, or at least another way, to be able to exclude (hide) rows from the results of the search and also hide rows from the whole table.

So in the first input field I search for COKE and I get:

```
COKEC001-PAVM-NYC
COKEC001-PAVM-LON
COKEC001-ABCD-NYC
COKEC001-ABCD-LON
COKEC001-ABCD-LON
COKEC002-ABCD-NYC
COKEC002-ABCD-LON
COKEC002-ABCD-LON
```

now I want to narrow that down to only LON, so I want to be able to type NYC into the Exclude input field. So basically the search is for COKE but not NYC.

Another example is searching for version numbers, search for 8.1 but not 8.1.17 .. that would return rows with 8.1, 8.1.2, 8.1.15, 8.1.18 ... many possibilities, but not 8.1.17 ... all those rows would be hidden.

So my feeling is there should be a search input field and an exclude input field that can work combined together.

I tried making a copy of the search function, and swapped the display styles at the end:

```
function myEFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myEInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and a new input field :

```
<input type="text" id="myEInput" onkeyup="myEFunction()" placeholder="Exclude names..">
```

The search on it's own works, the exclude on it's own works. But they don't work together.
I'm not well versed in javascript. Any help and ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please click edit, then the `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: You can use datatables, it provides a vast functionality(pagination/ search etc). 
Also you can use the pagination concept separately if data is too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make another search field text for the excludes names

```
<input type="text" id="myInputExclude" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for excludes names.."/>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  inputExclude = document.getElementById("myInputExclude");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  filterExclude = inputExclude.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      txtValue = txtValue.toUpperCase()
      let match = true
      let f = true // add this line
      filter.split(' ').forEach(q => {
        if(q && q.length > 0) {
          // and add these lines 
          if(f) { 
            match = false
            f = false
          }
          match = match || txtValue.indexOf(q) > -1  /// only change && instead ||
        } 
     })
      filterExclude.split(' ').forEach(q => {
        if(q && q.length > 0) 
          match = match && txtValue.indexOf(q) == -1
      })
      if (match) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You should also think about doing a "debounce" in your code. when you type something fast in the filter the query is delayed due to the number of elements

```
const debounce = (funct, time) => {
    let timeoutId;
    return function() {
        if(timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId)
        }
        const context = this
        const args = arguments
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            funct.apply(context, args)
        }, time);
    }
}
```

Now on keyup

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="debounce(myFunction(), 500)" placeholder="Search for names.."/>
<input type="text" id="myInputExclude" onkeyup="debounce(myFunction(), 500)" placeholder="Search for excludes names.."/>
```

This will give you a little time between typing so you don't see a delay

Comment: This is fantastic .. thanks very much. You left the () out after myFunction in the last line, but otherwise it works great. I really appreciate it. At first I didn't realize it was all one function, I thought it was an additional function. But I figure it out and got it woking. It helps filter the data so much. Thanks again.

Comment: So I'm using this to search for something but NOT something else. Is  there anyway that the Search input field can take 2 search terms, so that I can search for something AND something else. When I start typing "abc" results appear, but then I type space and all results disappear. I was hoping to type "abc xyz" and find all matching the two terms. If not, no worries. Thanks again.

Comment: yes, there is a way to, I am going to edit my response in a while

Comment: Again, thank you very much. The exclude successfully hides all rows that match xyz and all rows that match abc (which in itself is a bonus). But searching for "abc xyz" finds only rows that have both in the same row. So it doesn't find abc001-pavm-nyc AND xyz001-pavm-lon .... it only finds habc-001xyzw-lon. I'm still looking in case I've done something wrong.

Comment: what exactly you want

Comment: I see, you want one OR other isn't.... and for excluding none of them??

Comment: I already change `&&` instead `||` in `match = match || txtValue.indexOf(q) > -1`, check now

Comment: I tried to move this to chat but wasn't able to. Don't want to bother you too much as you have already been very helpful.  With || instead of && the Search input doesn't filter anything, all rows remain visible. I am trying to do the following. Searching for abc returns all rows that match abc, say 3 rows. Searching for "abc xyz" should return more rows, the 3 that have abc and all the others that have xyz .The Exclude input is working just fine.

Comment: check now, added some lines..
you don't bother me at all, we are a community

Comment: This is awesome and excellent. It works great. It does exactly what I need. I can find all kinds of combinations of rows .. everything that ends in -hk -sg -la  .. and then exclude anything that I want. Thanks again. Next onto paginating the table.

Comment: Is there any way these search exclude boxes can work with Datatables with pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions while I wait for you to post HTML:

- Cache the cells, no need to get the rows on every keyup and then the first cells. Put

```
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tr td:first-child");
```

outside the function but it has to execute after the table is loaded

- add a style `.hide { display: none;}` and use

```
    const val = txtValue.toUpperCase(); 
    tr[i].classList.toggle("hide",val.indexOf(filter) === -1 || 
    arrayOfIgnore.includes(val))
```

where arrayOfIgnore gets its values from your second input field

Something like this which I cannot test until you show more code

```
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tr td:first-child"); 
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input",function() {
  const filter = this.value.toUpperCase();
  tds.forEach(td => {
    const txtValue = td.textContent; // always uppercase
    td.closest("tr").classList.toggle("hide", filter !== "" &&
     (arrayOfIgnore.includes(textValue) ||
     !txtValue.includes(filter)));
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was able to get the first reply working.